# Use CDI Scope Annotations on Spring (Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver doesn't work)

Tags: java, spring, cdi, spring-bean

I have an application using Spring Beans 3.2.1 and I need to define the Beans Scope with the CDI Scope Annotations (SessionScoped, RequestScoped and ApplicationScoped).

I'm using a custom scope resolver:

```
public class CustomSpringScopeResolver extends Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver {

        public CustomSpringScopeResolver() {
        registerScope(SessionScoped.class, WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION);
        registerScope(RequestScoped.class, WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        registerScope(ApplicationScoped.class, WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION);
    }

    @Override
    public ScopeMetadata resolveScopeMetadata(BeanDefinition definition) {
        ScopeMetadata metadata = new ScopeMetadata();
        metadata.setScopeName(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE);
        if (definition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
            AnnotatedBeanDefinition annDef = (AnnotatedBeanDefinition) definition;
            Set<String> annTypes = annDef.getMetadata().getAnnotationTypes();
            String found = null;
            for (String annType : annTypes) {
                Set<String> metaAnns = annDef.getMetadata().getMetaAnnotationTypes(annType);
                if ((metaAnns.contains("javax.inject.Scope")
                    || metaAnns.contains("javax.enterprise.context.NormalScope"))
                    && !annType.equals(Dependent.class.getName())) {
                    if (found != null) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Found ambiguous scope annotations on bean class [" +
                                definition.getBeanClassName() + "]: " + found + ", " + annType);
                    }
                    found = annType;
                    String scopeName = resolveScopeName(annType);
                    if (scopeName == null) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                "Unsupported scope annotation - not mapped onto Spring scope name: " + annType);
                    }
                    metadata.setScopeName(scopeName);
                }
            }
        }
        return metadata;
    }

}
```

The code works properly, the scope on metadata is seted with the right value, but my beans stay with the singleton scope ignoring my definitions.

Debuging the Spring code, I saw that Spring register the bean first with the singleton Scope and then they try to register another bean with my definitions but in the "checkCandidate" method, they find the old bean and ignore the new one.

```
protected boolean checkCandidate(String beanName, BeanDefinition beanDefinition) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!this.registry.containsBeanDefinition(beanName)) {
            return true;
        }
        BeanDefinition existingDef = this.registry.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
        BeanDefinition originatingDef = existingDef.getOriginatingBeanDefinition();
        if (originatingDef != null) {
            existingDef = originatingDef;
        }
        if (isCompatible(beanDefinition, existingDef)) {
            return false;
        }
        throw new ConflictingBeanDefinitionException("Annotation-specified bean name '" + beanName +
                "' for bean class [" + beanDefinition.getBeanClassName() + "] conflicts with existing, " +
                "non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [" + existingDef.getBeanClassName() + "]");
    }
```

Is there a way to set Spring to use the new bean instead of the old one?

Comment: How is your configuration done?

Comment: @M.Deinum
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com"
   scope-resolver="br.com.custom.web.aq.application.scope.resolver.CustomSpringScopeResolver" />

Comment: Doe you have other `component-scan` s or `@ComponentScan` annotations. If so make sure everyone is configured correctly.

Comment: I found another component-scan <context:component-scan base-package="br.com" /> in the application. When I remove Sprign stops to duplicate beans but I can't resolve applicationContext in my classes. I guess that Spring classes is not getting injected in my classes (br.com...) with the session-resolver.

Comment: Why would you need `applicationContext.xml` in your classes? Also which session resolver? I have no clue on what you mean with those snippets/comments and those look like a different question all together. Also are you sure that you are looking at the Spring managed classes?

Comment: I need the XmlWebApplicationContext to get beans by name. The Scope resolver is just to resolve the CDI Scope Annotations. This code is part of a framework that needs to work either in CDI and Spring. So when I use the component-scan with scope-resolver I can't get the ApplicationContext in my beans, and when I use the one without the scope resolver, all my beans stay with "singleton" scope.

Comment: As stated when using the `ApplicationContext` directly you are generally doing things the wrong way. You should use dependency injection not do a lookup.

Comment: I think when I use scope-resolver classes out of the base-package (br.com) isn't injected in my beans in the package. Ex org.springframework.SpringClass isn't injected in br.com.custom.MyClass. But I'm not sure about this

Comment: Sometimes I have to search beans by name. Ex. When I need to get an SessionScoped Bean inside a ApplicationScoped Bean.

Comment: No you don't. Spring will take care of that it will inject a proxy for the real object. Spring handles all that for you so you don't need  (nor should) do the lookup.

Comment: Spring maybe control this the right way, but CDI promote the SessionScope to ApplicationScope in this case. But there are other cases that we need to get beans by name.

Comment: If you are getting beans by name you are doing things wrong unless you are writing a framework then it **might** be right. Also why when using CDI you use Spring? If that is the case you don't need a custom resolver and can use plain Spring from CDI?

Comment: This code is part of a framework. The framework needs to work in both Spring and CDI because we have some applications using CDI and others using Spring. We need the resolver to make the CDI Scope Annotations works on Spring

Comment: I found the problem. it wasn't Spring beans that wasn't getting injected in my beans it was my beans with Application Scope thas wasn't instatiated. I guess that Spring 3.2.1 doesn't have Scope Application. I changed the resolver to make ApplicationScoped Beans turn singleton and it worked.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks for your help!